# PHP How to get column name again from mysqli_fetch_field in while loop

Tags: php, mysqli

It seems mysqli_fetch_field returns column name only first time in while loop. Below is my code

```
$LoginDetailsCon=mysqli_connect("100.100.100.100","root","root","db") or     die("Failed to connect to DB: " . mysqli_connect_error()); 
$LoginDetailsQuery="SELECT * FROM ewh WHERE UserName = 'SomeName' AND Date     BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-09-30'";
$LoginDetailsResult=mysqli_query($LoginDetailsCon,$LoginDetailsQuery);
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($LoginDetailsResult,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
echo "1st time";
while($field=mysqli_fetch_field($LoginDetailsResult)) {
    $fieldname=$field->name;
    echo substr($fieldname,0,strlen($fieldname)-4) . "<br>";
}
echo "2nd time";
    while($field=mysqli_fetch_field($LoginDetailsResult)) {
    $fieldname=$field->name;
    echo substr($fieldname,0,strlen($fieldname)-4) . "<br>";
}
}
mysqli_close($LoginDetailsCon);
```

The result is like below

```
1st timeUser
colname1withoutlast4characters
colname2withoutlast4characters
colname3withoutlast4characters
2nd time1st time2nd time1st time2nd time
```

I need to fetch column names in while loop to get results from specific columns only and put into an array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need mysqli_fetch_field. that's useless function, and I have no idea why so many php users are trying to make any use of it.

Every time you fetch a row, you already have all the field names as **resulting row array's keys.**

```
$con = mysqli_connect("100.100.100.100","root","root","db")); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ewh WHERE UserName = 'SomeName' AND Date BETWEEN '2015-09-01' AND '2015-09-30'";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $fields = array_keys($row);
    foreach ($fields as $name) {
        // do whatever
    }
}
```